# MVC Helper prefix property name for child object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have hierarchical model as below.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyFilters Filters {get;set;}
}

public class MyFilters
{
   public string State {get;set;}
}
```

and im using Html helper to create control

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Filters.State)
```

when the page renders its creating the html element as below

```
 <input name="Filters.State" id="Filters_State" type="text" value=""/>
```

Its prefixing property name "Filters" to ID & NAME attribute. How do i tell MVC not to prefix property name to ID and NAME attribute. So the control will look like

```
 <input name="State" id="State" type="text" value=""/>
```

Comment: Of course it is. If it did not, you would never get model binding.

Comment: Do NOT change the name attribute. What is it that you are really trying to do? If you posting back `MyFilters` rather than `MyModel` then use the `[Bind(Prefix = "..")]` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always can set it with one of `TextBoxFor` overloads:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filters.State, htmlAttributes: new { Name = "State", id = "State"})
```

Comment: But then it won't bind on POST.

Comment: @CodeCaster I can't see controller signature here and binding depends on it.

Comment: i havent tried, but i think this work, It will override TextBoxFor default behaviour